# Use a conditional statement in a SQL Update query

Tags: sql, sql-update, oracle12c

I have the following Update query in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
UPDATE CSTAPP_O.F_AUDIT T1 SET
   T1.AUDIT_STATUS = v_Status,
   T1.ESCALATED = v_Escalated,
   T1.CSE_LAN = v_CSEID,
   T1.BUILD_CSE_LAN = v_CSEBuildID,
   T1.LOAD_DT = v_SubDt,
   T1.AUDITOR_LAN_ID = v_AuditorID,
   T1.AUDIT_START_DT = v_AStartDt,
   T1.WORK_ORDER_NUM = v_TransCIT
WHERE AUDIT_ID = v_AuditID
  AND CUST_NUM = v_CustNum
;
```

What I want to do is something like:

```
UPDATE CSTAPP_O.F_AUDIT T1 SET
   T1.AUDIT_STATUS = v_Status,
   T1.ESCALATED = v_Escalated,
   T1.CSE_LAN = v_CSEID,
   T1.BUILD_CSE_LAN = v_CSEBuildID,
   T1.LOAD_DT = v_SubDt,
   T1.AUDITOR_LAN_ID = v_AuditorID,
   T1.AUDIT_START_DT = v_AStartDt,
   T1.WORK_ORDER_NUM = v_TransCIT

   -- This is where the conditional piece is
   If T1.AUDIT_STATUS = 1 Then
     T1.AUDIT_END_DT = v_EndDt
   End If
   -- End of conditional piece

WHERE AUDIT_ID = v_AuditID
  AND CUST_NUM = v_CustNum
;
```

In other words, I only want to update the Audit_End_Dt if Audit_Status = 1.  Otherwise, I don't want to touch the Audit_End_Dt at all.

Is this possible?  If so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case`:

```
audit_end_dt = (case when T1.AUDIT_STATUS = 1 Then v_EndDt else audit_end_dt end)
```

I am guessing, though, that you want the new version of the status.  If so:

```
audit_end_dt = (case when v_status = 1 Then v_EndDt else audit_end_dt end)
```